# QSqlQuery not working

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

So I have this problem basically, I cannot exec my QsqlQuery.
I am connected to a SQLite database and I have checked that it is really connected.

```
QString databaseName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open database"),
                                                        "",
                                                        tr("Databáze (*.db)"));
mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
mydb.setDatabaseName("databaseName");

if (!mydb.open()) {
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Databáze nebyla připojena!",2000);
    databaseCheck = false;
}
else if (mydb.open()) {
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Databáze byla úspěšně připojena.",2000);
    databaseCheck = true;
}
```

This is part of the code from the `Mainwindow.cpp` which sets up the database connection. The database is declared in `mainwindow.h`, all is functioning in this part.

Here I got a form which returns some data about an employee that I want to create in the database. `databaseCheck` is a bool that tells me if the database is connected properly. And those variables `name`, `surname` etc. in this case are declared in `mainwindow.h` as `QString`.

```
if (databaseCheck) {
    form = new Form(this);
    form->setWindowTitle("Formulář informací o zaměstnanci.");
    form->exec();

    name = form->getName();
    surname = form->getSurname();
    id = form->getId();
    date = form->getDate();
    telephone = form->getTelephone();
    salary = form->getSalary();
    state = form->getState();

    QSqlQuery query(mydb);
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO employees (jmeno,prijmeni,datumnarozeni,telefon,plat,stav) "
                      "VALUES (:name, :surname, :date, :telephone, :salary , :state)");
    query.bindValue(":name", name);
    query.bindValue(":forename", surname);
    query.bindValue(":date", date );
    query.bindValue(":telephone", telephone);
    query.bindValue(":salary", salary);
    query.bindValue(":state", state );
    query.exec();
}
```

After I fill up the form with some data about the employee and accept it, it does not send anything to the database. I am checking the database with DB Browser for SQLite and the table `employees` is totally empty. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Also sorry for the Czech words, but i do it as user friendly program for czech users. Anyways the czech words are not necessary for the solution of this problem, so they can be ignored.

Comment: Check the erorr returned by QSqlQuery::lastError()

Comment: Sure you have write permission ?

Comment: `query.bindValue(":surname", surname);`.

Comment: Holy hell, I can see it now. If this was it... I am gonna be mad at myself, such pesky error.

Comment: Nope. Still says **QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")**  but thanks anyways.

Comment: @Vitolinux. In that case, one of the field names in your query is probably misspelled (or somehow just doesn't match what is in the sql schema). The error message doesn't lie - there must be mismatched parameters in the query.

Comment: @ekhumoro That's the problem, everything is the same as in the SQL table headers. Could there be problem that there is ID header in the SQL table too and i am starting from the name which is second after the ID in the SQL table? If you get me.

Comment: Check again. They ***cannot*** be the same. Just a guess: are you using any accented characters in the table names?

Comment: @ekhumoro I am not. They are really the same that is the problem. I compared it side to side, there is no spelling mistake in the words.

Comment: @ekhumoro Could it be the problem with the write permission? As Marco suggested, I didn't get what he meant though.

Comment: One way or another, the names in your query do not and cannot match what is in currently in `mydb`. So another guess: you did not load the db properly, and it is currently empty. Check `mydb.tables()`.

Comment: Is this your actual code: `mydb.setDatabaseName("databaseName");`?

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes the db is empty, there is just the empty table with the headers, i want my program to load data from it to the table.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes it is. It's the name that i get from the dialog, i search for my database manually.

Comment: So the path of your database is literally "databaseName" and not the contents of the variable `databaseName`?

Comment: It's the content of the databaseName, or atleast i hope it is. The databaseName contains **C:/Users/Adolf/Documents/projects/evidenceZamestnancu/mydatabase.db** after i search for it by the dialog.

Comment: HOLY SH**. I see those " " now. LOL What an amateur mistake... If that was it the whole time...

Comment: @ekhumoro Dude i am so much in debt to you, Thank you it was that problem... and I am looking for a solution for about two days. Sometimes the details really matter. Thank you again it works now...

Comment: No problem. In your defence, that error message, although strictly true, is pretty misleading.

Comment: @ekhumoro yep. I searched through the web what could it be and i saw posts which said that this error message is pretty undefined so its misleading by design :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL seems correct, the best approach is probably to write something like this.

```
if (!query.exec())
      qDebug() << query.lastError();
```

Comment: What did you mean by write permission? Is it something to be set in the program? I am the admin on my PC so if its not a windows thing then i dont know how you meant it. PS the last error says: **QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")**